# Angular + Jasmine testing with $timeout

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a jasmine test that runs angular components:

```
it("has correct MWF classes", function(done) {
  let element = $compile(markup)(localScope);
  localScope.$apply();
  setTimeout(function() {
    expect(element.html().indexOf("xxx")).not.toEqual(-1);
  }, localScope.selectTimeout);
});
```

"markup" has some custom component and that component has $postlink where I have a code that is under

```
this.$timeout(() => {xxxx }, 0);
```

When I run my test I found that xxxx code is not called when my test runs.

Any clue why any code under $timeout is not executed in test? The component works fine in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While testing use `$timeout.flush()` to flush the queue of pending timeout tasks.

You can use `$timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks()` to verify that there are no pending tasks that need to be flushed.